# How to find the inverse of f(x) in NTRU key generation?

Tags: encryption, public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, ntru

I work on a project that depends on the [NTRU cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRU), but I don't know how to find the inverse of $f(x)$.

Please see the picture:

> [image: Example of NTRU key generation]

Please help me to understand this problem.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$This somewhat oblique notation $F_q(x) = f(x)^{-1} \pmod q$ means that $F_q$ is the inverse of a unit element $f$ in the [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) $(\Z/q\Z)[x]/(P)$ of the [polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Quotient_ring_of_K.5BX.5D) $(\Z/q\Z)[x]$ by the ideal generated by some monic irreducible polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients.  $P$ is a system parameter presumably defined in an earlier slide.  Given $P$ and $f$, you can compute $F_q$ with the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

The notation is presumably chosen because we variously map the same polynomial expressions with integer coefficients of $P$, $f$, and $g$ into three different polynomial rings, $\Z[x]$, $(\Z/q\Z)[x]$, and $(\Z/p\Z)[x]$ at different times.  It wouldn't be quite right to say that $f$ *is* an element of $(\Z/q\Z)[x]/(P)$, because in the next sentence $f$ will be an element of $(\Z/p\Z)[x]/(P)$ instead.  Saying $a(x) = b(x) \pmod q$ means we are taking the base ring of the polynomials $a$ and $b$ to be $\Z/q\Z$ for that equation.